# How to view raw binary data as an image with given width and height?

Tags: linux

Does there exist a program for Linux that can display raw binary data?

Each byte in my binary files represent a pixel, so it would be very useful if something like this exists where I could say

```
program_name --input=dat001.bin --width=200 --height=100
```

and it would display the pixels.

I wonder if gnuplot, can be used for this...?

Comment: Question does not make sense.  To display raw binary data, it must be converted to a human readable form.  Usually this form is hexadecimal, which you can use `hd` to format.  Then you ask to see an image.  If it is an image, then it is going to be in an image format ( like bmp ) that will at the very least, have a header that identifies the format, the width, height, color depth, and maybe also have a color palette attached.

Comment: @psusi While the title would be better _How to display raw pixel data_, the intent of this question is clear, and totally makes sense to me. ("I want a program to let me specify the image meta data") Does it make more sense in hindsight (or perhaps after editing) to you also?

Comment: @NathanKidd, ahh, yes.. if you know it is an image using a specific format but has no header, rather than being just arbitrary binary data... got ya.

Comment: ffmpeg can to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15037011/5447906

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, gnuplot can do it.

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/image.html

Answer (score 16):

To see the "raw binary data", I would use the hex dump command `hexdump`†. I would use the `-C` option so that I could more easily see telltale ASCII text such as `JFIF` or `PNG` in case the data was not raw but a more structured form.

```
$ hexdump -C example.img
00000000  ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46  49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48  |......JFIF.....H|
00000010  00 48 00 00 ff db 00 43  00 06 04 05 06 05 04 06  |.H.....C........|
00000020  06 05 06 07 07 06 08 0a  10 0a 0a 09 09 0a 14 0e  |................|
00000030  0f 0c 10 17 14 18 18 17  14 16 16 1a 1d 25 1f 1a  |.............%..|
00000040  1b 23 1c 16 16 20 2c 20  23 26 27 29 2a 29 19 1f  |.#... , #&')*)..|
00000050  2d 30 2d 28 30 25 28 29  28 ff db 00 43 01 07 07  |-0-(0%()(...C...|
00000060  07 0a 08 0a 13 0a 0a 13  28 1a 16 1a 28 28 28 28  |........(...((((|
00000070  28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28  28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28  |((((((((((((((((|
*
00000090  28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28  28 28 28 28 28 28 ff c0  |((((((((((((((..|
000000a0  00 11 08 00 80 00 64 03  01 22 00 02 11 01 03 11  |......d.."......|
000000b0  01 ff c4 00 1d 00 00 01  04 03 01 01 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

I don't know of any image format that consists of unstructured bytes - is the data 8-bit RGB values? If the file contains 30000 bytes is that RGB for 100x100 pixels or RGB for 50x200 pixels or RGB for 200x50 pixels or something else? Is there a palette? You have to know something about the organisation of the data!

To view it as an image I would use the [NetPBM utilities](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) or maybe [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert it to a form understood by an image viewer

If the above can't do the job I'd investigate writing a small [Perl script](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861967)

---

Footnote:

† On some older Unix systems this command might be `hd` or `od` with no `hexdump` command available. See [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17319/can-hd-and-od-replace-each-other). `od` is POSIX and `od -Ax -tx1z filename` works in some popular Linux distributions.

Comment: Where can I get this? I just did `yum search hd` on my Fedora desktop, and it didn't have it.

Comment: OKay. I need to see the pxiels as graphic...

Comment: The binary might be called `hexdump`. On SuSE it is in the `util-linux` package.

Comment: FWIW it's also `hexdump` in Arch.

Answer (score 16):

**`convert` from ImageMagick**

E.g., an 8-bit 2x3 grayscale:

```
printf '\x00\xFF\x88\xFF\x00\xFF' > in.bin
```

Then:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 3x2+0 gray:in.bin out.png
```

Command explanation:

- `-depth 8`: each color has 8 bits
- `-size 2x3+0`: `2x3` image. `+0` means starting at offset 0 in the file. If there are metadata headers, you can skip them with the offset.
- `gray:in.bin`: the input file is `in.bin`, and the format is `gray`, as defined at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php This weird notation is used because ImageMagick usually determines the format from the extension, but here there is no extension.

**How to view such tiny outputs like this example**

The problem now is how to view the such a tiny 3x2 output accurately. A direct `eog`:

```
eog out.png
```

is not very good because the image is too small, and if you zoom in a lot `eog` uses a display algorithm that mixes up pixels continuously, which is better for most pictures, but not for such a tiny image.

One good possibility is to run:

```
convert out.png -scale 300x out2.png
```

or directly in one go with:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 3x2+0 gray:in.bin -scale 300x out.png
```

`-scale` is needed instead of `-resize`, since `-resize` mixes pixel colors continuously up much like `eog` by default.

Output:

[image]

Anther option is to view it in Gimp:

```
gimp out.png
```

Image editors such as Gimp must show every single pixel separately if you zoom in enough.

**RGB example**

```
printf '\xFF\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x00\x00\x00\xFF' > in.bin
convert -depth 8 -size 3x1+0 rgb:in.bin out.png
```

or with the `-scale` to make it more viewable:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 3x1+0 rgb:in.bin -scale 300x out.png
```

[image]

Related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/147554/what-software-can-display-raw-bitmaps-on-linux

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, ImageMagick 6.8.9.

Comment: Another example: if you have a file in RGBA format (say `/tmp/tex1.dat`), you can view the converted image directly with Imagemagick's `display` as 128x256 pixel image with `display -depth 8 -size 128x256+0 RGBA:/tmp/tex1.dat`

Comment: What if the pixels have 10 ot 12 bits ? I have tried the `-endian` option but it seems that it works as the `-depth 16`, the image is very dark

Comment: @sop not sure about 10 12. 12 might work with depth 12? 10 I expect you to need to specify further how many bits per channel, since 10 is not divisible by 4 (RGBA) nor 3 (RGB). Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 6):

If not wanting to view it directly but rather convert it the [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) utility can do this:

To read from stdin, assuming 320 x 200 pixels, 8 bit gray, header of 0, saving to pic.png in PNG format.

```
convert -depth 8 -size 320x200+0 gray:- pic.png
```

Comment: For newbs like me: `gray:-` means format `gray` and `-` means from stdin. Thus the current command hangs waiting for stdin. I've explained it further on my answer: http://superuser.com/a/978432/128124

Answer (score 0):

Raw binary data can be easily converted to [binary pgm format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm) by adding the header:

```
echo "P5
200 100
255
"$(cat dat001.bin) > dat001.pgm
```